# Trying to install web2py on a shared server (Dreamhost)

Tags: web-development, apache2, linux, python

I've been trying to install web2py on a subdomain on my shared account at Dreamhost. There used to be some info in their knowledge base, but it has been removed for outdated. I've found lots of tutorials, but most date back at least 6 years.
The website of `flup` is confusing - the dates of the forum seem all wrong (comments of version 0.9 are more recent that those of 1.0.3xxx).

Seemingly [one of the most applicable 'recipes'](http://www.web2pyslices.com/slice/show/1401/web2py-on-shared-hosting-hostmonster-with-fastcgi) installs well, but produces a `500` error. When I try to execute the `web2py.fcgi`, it reports `Premature end of script`. No obvious errors in the Apache logs.

I started Python from the virtual environment manually. `import sys` worked well, but `from flup.server.fcgi_fork import WSGIServer` caused an error which was apparently a Python 2/3 incompatibility. Installing an earlier version of `flup` did the trick.

Now, executing (still manually) `import gluon.main` produces: `ImportError: No module named gluon.main`. I can understand that - `gluon` is not in the `sys.path`. I can't imagine the instructions being so wrong, so it's probably something I'm doing.

- Anyone know about a reliable install recipe for web2py on a remote shared server?
- Or a pointer to a good description on how Apache, and web2py are supposed to communicate with each other (role of `flup`, `WSGI'...)
- Is there any way to get more info for debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I wasn't able to get things working following this tutorial, and many tests and variations.

Finally, I found [**a very interesting link**](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html?highlight=web2py) in the uWSGI site, which actually made things work!

The only issue left, is enabling `https` without self-signed certificates. I'll post another question, as it seems to be a separate matter.

**UPDATE:** By 'accident', I encountered [this recipe](https://aubreymoore.github.io/blog/posts/setting-up-web2py2-on-dreamhost/), which today (Jan 2022) works perfectly. Just be careful to substitute the correct user name in all lines where necessary. (Cheers, Aubrey!)